# ios - Control some values of AutoLayout at runtime

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, autolayout

I'm trying to implement custom slider and I want the slider's y position to be set in auto layout (center Y to the bar) but I want to control X position in code (so it is = 0 unless I do something with it)

Everything seems fine, but everytime auto-layout updates slider's x position goes to 0. How can I fix that?

Another thing I thought of is to make a reference to constraint between slider and the bar, but the problem with that is I don't know how to make a constraint between slider's center and bar's left side.

Comment: Make a left edge alignment constraint and set the `constant` appropriately - you will need to use the size of your slider - something like `slider.frame.size.width/2`

Comment: if I'd make left edge alignment constraint, will it affect the center of the slider or the it's upper left corner?

Comment: well, this is not that elegant as I wanted, but that did its thing, I'll accept as answer.